# Is it possible to have the windows batch command line interpret ~ as %USERPROFILE%?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm wondering if there is any modification I can perform to the windows registry or creating some wrapper around cmd.exe which allows ~ to be interpreted as %USERPROFILE%

The basic use case is that I have a large number of simple bash scripts which are only incompatible with windows batch because of the ~. I have scripts to convert bash to bat, but most of the time I use these I simply open the file and copy-paste the line into my command prompt. On windows I always have to sub in %USERPROFILE% for ~.

Something else that would work is if I could make windows look at environ variables like: $var as %var%

I doubt there is anything I can do to get the copy-paste functionality that I want, but I figured I'd at least ask.

Comment: Why don't you have the script that converts the bash scripts to batch just replace all uses of `~` with `%USERPROFILE%`?

Comment: If the batch files are only going to be run by one particular user, you could try creating a junction point named ~ and pointing to the relevant folder.

Answer (score 0):

This code can automate it for you - it's a native Windows sed-like tool.

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
type script.file |repl "~" "\x25userprofile\x25" x >new.script.file
```